# Support for object level Tagging in boto3 upload_file method

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, awss3transfermanager

I want to add tags to the files as I upload them to S3. Boto3 supports specifying tags with put_object method, however considering expected file size, I am using upload_file function which handles multipart uploads. But this function rejects 'Tagging' as keyword argument.

```py
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-west-2')
client.upload_file('test.mp4', 'bucket_name', 'test.mp4',
                   ExtraArgs={'Tagging': 'type=test'})

ValueError: Invalid extra_args key 'Tagging', must be one of: ACL, CacheControl, ContentDisposition, ContentEncoding, ContentLanguage, ContentType, Expires, GrantFullControl, GrantRead, GrantReadACP, GrantWriteACP, Metadata, RequestPayer, ServerSideEncryption, StorageClass, SSECustomerAlgorithm, SSECustomerKey, SSECustomerKeyMD5, SSEKMSKeyId, WebsiteRedirectLocation
```

I found a way to make this work by using S3 transfer manager directly and modifying allowed keyword list.

```py
from s3transfer import S3Transfer
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-west-2')
transfer = S3Transfer(client)
transfer.ALLOWED_UPLOAD_ARGS.append('Tagging')
transfer.upload_file('test.mp4', 'bucket_name', 'test.mp4',
                     extra_args={'Tagging': 'type=test'})
```

Even though this works, I don't think this is the best way. It might create other side effects. Currently I am not able to find correct way to achieve this. Any advice would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

`Tagging` directive is now supported by [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig). You can do the following to add tags:

```
import boto3

from urllib import parse

s3 = boto3.client("s3")

tags = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}

s3.upload_file(
    "file_path",
    "bucket",
    "key",
    ExtraArgs={"Tagging": parse.urlencode(tags)},
)
```

Comment: What does the format of parse.urlencode(tags) look like? Can we not just pass a dict?

Comment: ExtraArgs should be a dictionary of {"string": "string"}, so one should convert the dict into a string. parse.urlencode returns a string in the expected format: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/devguide/API_Tag.html

Answer (score 0):

The [S3 Customization Reference — Boto 3 Docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig) documentation lists valid values for `extra_args` as:

> ALLOWED_UPLOAD_ARGS = ['ACL', 'CacheControl', 'ContentDisposition', 'ContentEncoding', 'ContentLanguage', 'ContentType', 'Expires', 'GrantFullControl', 'GrantRead', 'GrantReadACP', 'GrantWriteACP', 'Metadata', 'RequestPayer', 'ServerSideEncryption', 'StorageClass', 'SSECustomerAlgorithm', 'SSECustomerKey', 'SSECustomerKeyMD5', 'SSEKMSKeyId', 'WebsiteRedirectLocation']

Therefore, this does not appear to be a valid way to specify a tag.

It appears that you might need to call [`put_object_tagging()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object_tagging) to add the tag(s) after creating the object.